# Installing SDL Web 8.0 – Content Delivery Setup

Tags: content-delivery, web8

Please share steps for  "Installing SDL Web 8 – Content Delivery Setup", because the steps provided in SDL website (http://docs.sdl.com/) asking to execute script "quickinstall.ps1" but there is not such file and folder in SDL web 8.0 installation zip. This script is provided in SDL web 8.1.1 zip. So what are the options here to move on

1. Instead of using script what are the required manual steps for web 8.0.
2. Can we copy paste the additional scripts and folders provided in web 8.1.1 under Content Delivery/resources and continue the installation by executing script quickinstall.ps1

Comment: Any reason why you would not use 8.1.1?

Comment: @NunoLinhares I saw no issue in using 8.1.1 and if its recommended from SDL to use 8.1.1 instead of 8.0 with listed benefits and issues covered in 8.1.1 I can approach the project owners to get a go signal. Also  in that case if I go for 8.1.1 do i need to delete/uninstall below steps already completed using 8.0 installation zip. ? please confirm 1)Creation of below databases using scripts (Tridon_cm,Tridon_Broker,XPM,Topology_mgr)
2)Installation of Content Manager

Comment: There are upgrade scripts provided in 8.1.1, so you don't need to start from scratch there. We obviously recommend 8.1.1, as it includes quite a lot of fixes. Full list of fixes: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-CE302056-D249-45E2-9016-531093A626CC

Comment: Just a small note... 8.0 was the cloud release, so you are not installing that, you are installing 8.1. Convincing your management to use 8.1.1 instead should be fairly easy I would hope.